# What does at sign before eval() in php means?

Tags: php, eval, sign

I've obfuscated a simple PHP 'hello world' program. The result is this :-

```
$e5b592e3="\x62\x61\x73\145\x36\64\137\144\x65\143\157\144\145";@eval($e5b592e3("Ly9oOWsxZGZrZzhpaTRJSzcxd2pIL3FhSkxJZERJM2ovZHpZZ2NmNTMwSXJKVk
```

(I've shown only relevant part of the code.)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PHP`, `@` before a `function` is used  to suppress any **warnings** or **errors** it may throw.